# `PortableClient` constructor failing after moving project

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library, portable-rest

I have a portable class library project that I have just moved out of a totally portable solution into one where only certain projects are portable. The PCL project uses the `PortableRest` library for communicating with some web services. As soon as I moved the PCL project into my bigger project, I started getting an exception on the line:

```
var client = new RestClient();
```

If I place the same code into a new, non-portable class library, that same line of code works fine. This code also works fine in the PCL code, but only in its original solution, not the new one, so besides `PortableRest.RestClient` being fully intended to run in a portable project, it does in its home project, just not the new one.

The exception I get on that ctor line is:

```
MissingMethodException: "Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression(System.Net.DecompressionMethods)'."
```

Maybe worth emphasising: I have not changed any code at all. Only moved the project that uses `PortableClient` from one solution to another.

Comment: Do you mean you just moved existing projects into a different solution? How are you referring to PortableRest - perhaps your solution has a different NuGet package version, for example?

Comment: Yes, I moved the PCL from the PCL oriented solution into the main solution .Both solutions seem to be using the same NuGet for PortableRest, i.e. 3.0.1

Comment: The problem probably lies in the [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) that *PortableRest* is dependent upon. These libraries uses the ["bait-and-switch"](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/) technique when applying the target-specific DLLs to the projects in your solution. When you change PCL profile NuGet probably assigns a new set of *HTTP Client* DLLs to your project, in which the `AutomaticDecompression` setter is not included for some unfortunate reason. Which PCL profiles are you switching from and to?

Comment: I encounter the same error when using RestSharp.Portable 3.1.3 and RestSharp.Portalbe.HttpClient 3.1.3 in a Xamarin PCL project .  I manual update the Microsoft.Net.Http to 2.2.29 but still no luck. any ideas?